# firstOrCreate not adding attribute therefore failing to create model

Tags: php, laravel

I have this usual User model table

```
Id | name | email | nullable column | password | nullable column | timestamps | ROLE
```

When using `firstOrCreate` or `firstOrNew`

```
$user = User::firstOrNew([
            'email' => $user->email
        ], [
            'name' =>  $user->name,
            'password' => Hash::make(Str::random(24)),
            'role' => 0
        ]);
```

getting this message `General error: 1364 Field 'role' doesn't have a default value`

which I fiend weird since I'm passing `role` with attributes.

Found that if I pass -only with `firstOrCreate`- the `$user->role` then `$user->save` I succeed but I'm not sure if that workaround will give me trouble in the future. ¿Am I not overriding existing users role with this fix? I'd definetly prefer to simply use `firstOrCreate`.

Comment: Did you add `role` to $fillable variable on your User model?

Comment: adding `role` to `$fillable` at User model solved the `firstOrCreate` issue. Thank you @HenryBui.

Comment: The real reason is Mass Assignment, you can read more here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment